# How to create a function that uses 2 integers from 2 different lists and adding the pair to a certain integer?

Tags: python

Doing some basic python coding. Here is the problem I was presented.

Create a function that takes 3 inputs:

- Two lists of integers
- one integer **n**

Prints the pairs of integers, one from the first input list and the other form the second list, that adds up to **n**. Each pair should be printed.

**Final Result (Example)**:

pair([2,3,4], [5,7,9,12], 9)

2 7

4 5

I'm still awfully new to Python, studying for a test and for some reason this one keeps giving me some trouble. This is an intro course so basic coding is preferred. I probably won't understand most advanced coding.

Comment: show us your attemps

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as you stated this is for a basic coding class so the answer is most likely already out there.

Comment: How do i edit my question to change it then? That link did not help by the way.

Comment: `def pair(x,y,n):` 
`for i in x and y:`
              if x[i]+y[i] == n:
                   print(x[i],y[i])`

Comment: Nevermind, I can't even figure out to type out my code.....................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest naieve approach would be to just test all possible combinations to see if they add up.

```
def pair(list1, list2, x):
    for a in list1:
        for b in list2:
            if a + b == x:
                print a, b
```

There are more efficient ways to do it (eg. ignore duplicates, ignore numbers greater than `x`, etc.)

If you wanted to do it in a single loop, python has some convenience functions for that

```
from itertools import product

for a, b in product(list1, list2):
    if a + b == x:
        print a, b
```

Comment: I believe that your function should return all of the combinations, not print them.  If you use `return`, you can use a list comprehension: `def pair(list1, list2, x): return [(a,b) for a in list1 for b in list2 if a + b == x]`

Comment: Question just said they needed to be printed.  Specifically, on different lines.  A lot of the online code problems work like this because it allows them to test a submission by just comparing stdout vs a known correct output.

Comment: This is perfect! I was trying to use a single for loop with "and" instead of a nested for loop. I had the nested at first but i wasn't sure if that was right. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Like I said this is super simple, I'm in an intro class.. Haven't had as much practice as some of my peers... :(

Comment: Thanks for the other option as well! To be honest, I  don't really know what "from" does or "itertools.product()" does either.